# Java - "while" with using not equal object >> not working

Tags: java

Why is the below code not working when using "!" not equals; it gave me "while" statement has an empty body? and when I'm removing the "!" it works...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = "";
        while (!input.equals("quit")); {
            System.out.print("Input : ");
            input = scanner.next().toLowerCase();
            System.out.println(input);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the code, rather than "code image".

Comment: It's better to add code directly here rather than image. And it;s because of ; at the end of while. Remove that.

Comment: What does 'not equal object >>' mean?

Answer (score 3):

you have to remove the semicolon

```
while(!input.equals("quit")) {
...
}
```

Comment: no problem. You can mark the answer as accepted if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `;` in the loop before `{`